# How to correctly upload shapefile into PostGIS on Ubuntu?

Tags: postgis, shapefile

I want to know how to use upload shapefile via Postgis. Can you please help me?

[image: I want to know how to use upload shapefile via PostGIS. Can you please help me?].com/nsVuQ.png

Comment: It looks to me like there's a problem with 'public', this depends a lot on how your postgis is set up. More detail is required to help. Is it possible you don't have permission to create/alter tables in the public schema? Are you importing as SuperUser?